# What are the most intense electromagnetic waves in nature?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

Basically as the title says.

I'm interested in the naturally occurring EM waves, and I would like to know the strongest EM waves out there. I'm not talking about "strong" as in energy per photon that is proportional to the frequency, but about the overall energy transported by the wave that is proportional to the square of the electric field; so, I guess another way to state the question is: Which naturally occurring waves have the highest electric fields?

Comment: Any electromagnetic field of sufficiently high intensity is no longer describable by classical electromagnetism, because the energy density of the field becomes high enough for spontaneous pair production by collision of photons to happen, the "reverse reaction" to matter-antimatter annihilation (the threshold at which this happens is called the Schwinger limit). Light-by-light scattering has recently been discovered in ultra-peripheral heavy-ion collisions at the LHC, so assuming that you can find the intensity by squaring the field may not be valid.

Comment: @probably Can you provide a reference for where those intensities occur in nature, as requested by OP?

Comment: You have to define "naturally". The sun spectrum ? the cosmic gamma ray bursts?  Or hunman constructions that generate light?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty If by "naturally" we mean "created without human intervention," one possible source for fields of that intensity is around active galactic nuclei. One of the proposed mechanisms for the production of a quasar jet is the Blandford-Znajek process (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blandford%E2%80%93Znajek_process), in which the electromagnetic fields near the central black hole become strong enough to induce vacuum breakdown and a pair-production cascade described at the microscopic level by light-by-light scattering.

Comment: @probably I agree that it's a pretty meaningless distinction, but the question is very clearly defined in those terms.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I agree, which is why I provided an example that is natural (that is, if it is in fact the mechanism by which quasar jets are generated).

Comment: I wasn't aware of naturally occurring macroscopic fields that are strong enough to create pair production. I was thinking about fields that while strong, are still below the Schwinger limit. And yes, by "naturally" I meant "created without human intervention".